# A fair coin is tossed eight times, find the probability that heads shows at the sixth toss but not earlier.

Tags: probability

I tried to solve this question like this:

$H_i =$ Heads at the ith toss

$P=P(H_6\cap H_7\cap H_8)=P(H_6)+P(H_7)+P(H_8)-p(H_6\cap H_7)-p(H_6\cap H_8)-p(H_7\cap H_8)+p(H_6\cap H_7\cap H_8)=3\times \frac{1}{2^8}-3\times \frac{1}{2^{16}}+\frac{1}{2^{24}}=0.01167...$

The only answer I found for this problem is $0.016$ which is different from my answer.

What is the correct approach to the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The last two tosses do not matter at all.  You need to get TTTTTH. What is the probability of that?  The given answer is an approximation-it would be better to leave it as a fraction.

Comment: The probability of getting head or tail remains constant from one toss to the next. Therefore probability of getting head at sixth toss is equal to the prbability of getting 5 tails followed by head $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^6}$$

Comment: thank you, @Ross Millikan

Comment: thanks a lot, @Harish Chandra Rajpoot

Answer (score 1):

It's the probability of showing five tails and then heads, which is $\left(\frac12\right)^5\frac12=\frac1{64}\approx0.016.$

Comment: your right, I'm so stupid